# How to fix my grid items from disappearing when given a style attribute "Grid area"

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm setting up a page that has details of company employees. my problem is that i tried giving my grid items a "grid area" style attribute so that i can use the "grid name" when defining my grid template areas for my container. but suddenly my items disappear. Please what do i need to do to fix the problem ?

```
 .container{
         border-right: 2px solid grey;
         border-left: 2px solid grey;
         display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
         grid-gap: 10px;
         justify-items: center;
         margin-top: 100px; 
         grid-template-areas {
         "head head head"
         "  .  side  ."
         "foot foot foot";
    }
   }



.grid-1{
     display: grid;
     grid-area: head;
}
 .grid-2{
        display: grid;
        grid-area: side;

   }
    .grid-3{
        display: grid;
        grid-area: foot;
   }
```

i expect the output of my grid to still show irrespective of the "grid-area" style attribute used but it disappears.

Comment: Unless you are using some type of CSS preprocessor you can't nest CSS selectors like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for `grid-template-areas` is incorrect. The value should not be wrapped with curly braces, instead it should look like this:

```css
 .container{
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "head head head"
                       "  .  side  ."
                       "foot foot foot";
}

.grid-1{
  display: grid;
  grid-area: head;
  background-color: pink;
}
 .grid-2{
  display: grid;
  grid-area: side;
  background-color: blue;
}
.grid-3{
  display: grid;
  grid-area: foot;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="grid-1">Header</div>
 <div class="grid-2">Side</div>
 <div class="grid-3">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Japhheth The items in the code snippet I have shared do not disappear. If you're still having a problem then you may need to share more of your code

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) documentation, I see a segment which says:

> To get started you have to define a container element as a grid with `display: grid`, set the column and row sizes with `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows`, and then place its child elements into the grid with `grid-column` and `grid-row`.

I see your use of `grid-template-columns` but none of `grid-template-rows`. Changing `.container` to include `grid-template-rows` may help, something like this (for three rows):

```
.container{
         border-right: 2px solid grey;
         border-left: 2px solid grey;
         display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
         grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
         grid-gap: 10px;
         justify-items: center;
         margin-top: 100px; 
         grid-template-areas: "head head head"
                              "  .  side  ."
                              "foot foot foot";
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing that yet the items keep disappearing.

Comment: I'll see if I can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working by fixing the typo in `grid-template-areas` and defining `grid-auto-rows`. I'd suggest looking into some other CSS property that might be causing the issue since what you provided works pretty well with minor fixes.

```css
.container {
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
  border-left: 2px solid grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-areas: "head head head" ".  side  ." "foot foot foot";
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-1 {
  grid-area: head;
  display: grid;
}

.grid-2 {
  grid-area: side;
  display: grid;
}

.grid-3 {
  grid-area: foot;
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-item grid-1">Head</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-2">Side</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-3">Foot</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)